# Is this a cedar tree or juniper?

Tags: trees

[image]
What type of tree is this? It’s a transplant but my friend isn’t sure what it is. How big will it get?

Answer (score 2):

It appears to be a Juniper variety, judging by the pointed, juvenile leaves compared with the older, adult scale-like leaves lower down the stem. As to eventual size, impossible to say; there are several varieties of Juniper which vary widely in height, spread and growth habit. Maybe as it grows a bit and its habit of growth becomes clear, it might be possible to identify it, particularly if its prostrate.